# for-each no results text

Tags: xpath, foreach

I have a for-each and when there is nothing output by it I would like to display some default text.

If I have...

```
<xsl:for-each select='xpath'> Some content for each matching element result. </xsl:for-each>
```

What I would like is:

```
<xsl:for-each select='xpath'>
   <xsl:output-this-when-there-is-content> Some content for each matching element result. </xsl:output-this-when-there-is-content>
   <xsl:no-results-output> Some content for when the for-each finds no matches. </xsl:no-results-output>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough.  If I have...

<xsl:for-each select='xpath'>
   Some content for each matching element result.
</xsl:for-each>

What I would like is:

<xsl:for-each select='xpath'>
   <xsl:output-this-when-there-is-content>
      Some content for each matching element result.
   </xsl:output-this-when-there-is-content>
   <xsl:no-results-output>
      Some content for when the for-each finds no matches.
   </xsl:no-results-output>
</xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xpath"> ...
```

The you can do something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="xpath">
        <xsl:for-each select="xpath"> ...
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Some default text</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

To avoid the double test of the XPath (and duplication) you could probably use an `xsl:variable`, something like the following (syntax may be a little wrong, but the rough idea should be right).

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:variable name="elems" select="xpath"/>
    <xsl:when test="$elems">
        <xsl:for-each select="$elems"> ...
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Some default text</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Is there a faster method than testing the xpath query twice?

Comment: Thank you, I had not considered using the variable to store the result of the test
:)

Comment: Place the variable outside of the choose block.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the verbosity of the `<xsl:choose>` solution that Greg Beech proposed, you can do:

```
<xsl:variable name="elems" select="xpath"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$elems">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:if test="not($elems)">
  <xsl:text>Some default text</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

The `<xsl:variable>` is for efficiency, it avoids doing the same query twice.

The `<xsl:for-each>` only runs if there are any nodes in `$elems`, the `<xsl:if>` only runs if there are not.

Answer (score -1):

I would think sth like this would be good:

```
If (x!=null)
{
console.write("Default Text")}
else
{
foreach (var y in x)
{

       Console.Writeline(y);
    //...
}
}
```